# How can I combine two HashMap objects containing the same types using Generics and control what happens in case of duplicates

Tags: java, generics

java - How can I efficiently merge two Map objects containing the same types using Generics and control what happens in case there are duplicates (add or multiply if the values are Integer and Concat if the values are String)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [the following article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Add the elements of one map to the other one at a time using [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
  map1.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), (oldV, newV) -> /* some expression to combine old and new values */);
}
```

If you are using Java 7 or earlier, the above linked documentation shows how you can implement it without Java 8 features (in the "Implementation Requirements" section).

Comment: what in case when one map is bigger than other 1 (let's say map2 is much bigger than map1) and we don't know which one will be large?

Answer (score -1):

You can try like below example:

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("Java", 7);
map1.put("C#", 4);
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("Java", 3);
map1.put("Scala", 5);

map1.keySet().forEach(e -> {
    map2.computeIfPresent(e, (String key,Integer value)-> value+map1.get(key));
    map2.putIfAbsent(e, map1.get(e));
});

System.out.println(map2);
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to handle all of your use cases then you can do like below.

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("Java", 7);
map1.put("C#", 4);
Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("Java", 3);
map1.put("Scala", 5);

map1.keySet().forEach(e -> {
    map2.computeIfPresent(e, (String key, Object value) -> {
        if (value instanceof Integer)
            return Integer.sum((Integer) value, (Integer) map1.get(key));
        if (value instanceof String) {
            String s1 = (String) value;
            String s2 = (String) map1.get(key);
            return s1.concat(s2);
        }
        return null;
    });
    map2.putIfAbsent(e, map1.get(e));
});

System.out.println(map2);
```